# awk rounding the float numbers

Tags: bash, awk

My first line of file a.txt contains following and fields are separated by (,)

```
ab,b1,c,d,5.986627e738,e,5.986627e738
cd,g2,h,i,7.3423542344,j,7.3423542344
ef,l3,m,n,9.3124234323,o,9.3124234323
```

when I issue the below command

```
awk -F"," 'NR>-1{OFS=",";gsub($5,$5+10);OFS=",";print }' a.txt
```

it is printing

```
ab,b1,c,d,inf,e,inf
cd,g2,h,i,17.3424,j,17.3424
ef,l3,m,n,19.3124,o,19.3124
```

Here I have two issues

1. I asked awk to add 10 to only 5th column but it has added to 7th column as well due to duplicate entries
2. It is rounding up the numbers, instead, I need decimals to print as it is

How can I fix this?

Comment: why have you specified `NR>-1` ?

Comment: And why do you set OFS twice?

Comment: is the number `5.986627e738`  using scientific notation or typo and `e` shouldn't be there?

Comment: @SatyanveshMuppaneni you should add expected output to clear some doubts like use of `e` in fifth column, `NR>-1` etc... `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {split($5,a,"."); a[1]+=10; $5=a[1]"."a[2]}1' input_file`  might work if fifth column always has a `.`

Comment: @Sundeep and the increment must always be integer.  just `$5+=whatever`

Comment: @Kent yeah, increment only int... OP has values like `5.986627e738` ... with your answer, it gets converted to `10.0000000000` hence the comments asking OP to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}{$5=sprintf("%.10f", $5+10)}7' file
```

- in your data, the $5 from line#1 has an `e`, so it was turned into 10.0000... in output.
- you did substitution with `gsub`, therefore all occurrences will be replaced.
- printf/sprintf should be considered to output in certain format.

tested with gawk

#### If you want to set the format in `printf` dynamically:

```
kent$  cat f
ab,b1,c,d,5.9866,e,5.986627e738
cd,g2,h,i,7.34235,j,7.3423542344
ef,l3,m,n,9.312423,o,9.3124234323

kent$  awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}{split($5,p,".");$5=sprintf("%.*f",length(p[2]), $5+10)}7' f
ab,b1,c,d,15.9866,e,5.986627e738
cd,g2,h,i,17.34235,j,7.3423542344
ef,l3,m,n,19.312423,o,9.3124234323
```

Comment: and how it differs from the @123 answer?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest when I posted it, His answer didn't show up. and I think I explained why OP's solution didn't work and gave some suggestions.

Comment: explanation - yes, awk expression - No (plagiarism)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest according to OP's comment, now my answer is different from 123's. Is it ok now?

Comment: that's better now

Comment: kent, can you please tell what does that 7 is all about which you have added before filename

Comment: @SatyanveshMuppaneni it is same as 1. non -zero number in awk does default action - `print`

Comment: @Kent Thanks for your help

Comment: $5=sprintf("%.*f",length(p[2]), $5+10)     May I know what does that * indicates

Comment: $5=sprintf("%.*f",length(p[2]), $5*10)     May I know what does that * indicates. if I am trying to multiply with 10, in the result, it is appending 0 at the end

Comment: @SatyanveshMuppaneni `*` is for building the format string. that is, you can  give dynamic value for the length/precision etc.  E.g. `printf("%.*f", 3, 2.1234)` will give you `2.123`.  pls google and read printf format doc.

Answer (score 0):

what you did is replacement on the whole record, what you really want to do is

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
           {$5+=10}1' a.txt
```

Comment: How does this address their second issue?

Comment: thanks, karakfa, I need to work on this a bit to incorporate to my script and see if any issue. Give me some time I will get back

Comment: Thanks for your support